ComputeError: could not append value when creating Polars DataFrame from data
I'm encountering a ComputeError when trying to create a Polars DataFrame from a data. The error message is:
ComputeError: could not append value: 1.41431 of type: f64 to the builder; make sure that all rows have the same schema or consider increasing infer_schema_length it might also be that a value overflows the data-type's capacity
Here's the relevant part of my code using a reproducible json example (test.json):
import json
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
response = requests.get('https://github.com/user-attachments/files/16026717/test.json')
res = json.loads(response.text)

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(res) # Creating DataFrame using Pandas (works fine)
df = pl.DataFrame(res) # Creating DataFrame using Polars (raises the error)

I expected the pl.DataFrame(res) line to work similarly to the pd.DataFrame(res) line, but it raises the mentioned error. I've also noticed that a similar error was discussed in a closed GitHub issue for Polars, but I am still encountering this error despite using the latest version of Polars (0.20.31).
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on how to resolve this?
I checked the types of the values in res and they seem to be consistent. I also tried other things like rounding floating-point numbers to 5 decimal places or increasing infer_schema_length, but they didn't work and I got the same error again.

Can you check if some of the values are extrapolating the decimals or something like this? Just get column by column and double check what values would not fit on f64.

without an example the only thing I can guess to try would be pl.DataFrame(res, orient='row'). If that doesn't work then you'll have to provide a minimal and reproducible example of res that doesn't work.

@DeanMacGregor I created the reproducible example in test.json and updated the question. The error is still there you can check it out. I also opened an issue in the Polars GitHub: link

Does pl.DataFrame(res, orient="row", infer_schema_length=None) work?

Yes, thanks @jqurious. Setting infer_schema_length to None solves the problem.

I think this is happening for me with a single row when creating from a dict. Is there some other reason this error might happen for one row?

The problem was solved by setting infer_schema_length to None, thanks to jqurious
pl.DataFrame(res, infer_schema_length=None)

It seems the error was raised because the default value of infer_schema_length is 100. However, in our data, the type of that column can not be detected until a row that is bigger than 100.
I suggested in the GitHub issue to modify the error description so the users can debug their code easily by setting the parameter to None.
